# Alias of awk command - too many quotes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

Probably missing something simple here but I am not a shell scripting expert.

I have a local command that works perfectly.

```
tail -f /path/to/file | awk '
  /INFO/ {print "\033[32m" $0 "\033[39m"}
  /ERROR/ {print "\033[31m" $0 "\033[39m"} 
  /WARNING/ {print "\033[33m" $0 "\033[39m"}
'
```

If I ssh into my boxes and paste it in, it works well.  But I can't seem to alias it because it's already using both kinds of quotes, so `alias='...'` won't work.  I've also tried making it into a function:

```
function tailMyFile {
    tail -f /path/to/file | awk '
    /INFO/ {print "\033[32m" $0 "\033[39m"}
    /ERROR/ {print "\033[31m" $0 "\033[39m"} 
    /WARNING/ {print "\033[33m" $0 "\033[39m"}'; 
}
```

Which tells me: `-bash: /INFO/: No such file or directory`

Comment: That error from bash means it isn't seeing `/INFO/` as being in the single quoted awk script for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way of function declaration:

```
tailMyFile() {
    tail -f /path/to/file | awk '
    /INFO/ {print "\033[32m" $0 "\033[39m"}
    /ERROR/ {print "\033[31m" $0 "\033[39m"} 
    /WARNING/ {print "\033[33m" $0 "\033[39m"}'; 
}
```

However, it seems as though your error is not pertaining to how the functions is defined, but whether your /INFO/ directory is properly seen, can you `cd /INFO` without any problems?

Comment: improvement: change `/path/to/file` to `$1` and pass the file path as the argument to the function (i.e. `tailMyFile /path/to/file`). Then you can use the function with any file, not just one.

Comment: @Isaac that gave me an `syntax error near unexpected token `('`.  I tried prefixing it with `function`, but that gave me the same error as my original.

Comment: The snippet here is a perfectly valid function. If your shell doesn't like that something is wrong.

Comment: @EtanReisner I think I got a weird gremlin in there somewhere.  I tried retyping it from scratch character for character and it worked, but pasting it in from another shell made it not work even though they look identical.  Good catch - thanks.